# Call to a member function getResponse() on null in observer while generating the shipment in magento2.4.3

Tags: magento2, php, admin, event-observer, magento2.4.3

```
<event name="sales_order_shipment_save_before">
    <observer name="test_beforeshipment" instance="Module\ModuleName\Observer\BeforeShipment" />
</event>

public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    $shipment = $observer->getEvent()->getShipment();
    $order = $shipment->getOrder();
    $orderId = $order->getId();
    $redirectUrl = $this->url->getUrl('sales/order/view/order_id/'.$orderId);
    $this->responseFactory->create()->setRedirect($redirectUrl)->sendResponse();
    $observer->getControllerAction()->getResponse()->setRedirect($redirectUrl);
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: Working fine the same code on the Magento2.4.2 version, but not working the same on the 2.4.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do that then on __construct() function of your class observer, you must inject two classes.

First, \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory which is responsible for redirection,
Another class \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface will make a URL for that redirection.
Then create object for ResponseFactory, and using setRedirect($YourUrl)->sendResponse(); redirect to your wished URL.
Observer
https://pastebin.com/4HwLUrth

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply, But I have already applied the solution that you have added but It is not working on the 2.4.3 Magento Version

Comment: I am getting the issue in this line
$observer->getControllerAction()->getResponse()->setRedirect($redirectUrl);

Here getResponse() function returning null

Comment: @AbhayAgrawal did you find a solution? I am facing the same error :)

Comment: @Korbin Please use this 
$error = "YOUR CUSTOM MESSAGE";
throw new \Magento\Framework\Validator\Exception(__($error));

Comment: @Korbin check the above solution and let me know the update

Comment: I ended up using a plugin and a different approach, but tnx for checking. @AbhayAgrawal